# Custom UINavigationbar in UISplitViewController

Tags: iphone, ios5, uinavigationbar, uisplitviewcontroller

Having some problems with customizing the UINavigationController. The size change is working, but the (1px*60px) image is not working. The code is located in the MasterViewController.

Any ideas?

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (custom)

- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width,60);
    return newSize;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"navimg.png"];
    [image drawAsPatternInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0,self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-5_0/_index.html):

> In iOS 5, the `UINavigationBar`, `UIToolbar`, and `UITabBar` implementations have changed so that the `drawRect:` method is not called unless it is implemented in a subclass. Apps that have re-implemented `drawRect:` in a category on any of these classes will find that the `drawRect:` method isn't called. UIKit does link-checking to keep the method from being called in apps linked before iOS 5 but does not support this design on iOS 5 or later. Apps can either:
>
> - Use the customization API for bars in iOS 5 and later, which is the preferred way.
> - Subclass `UINavigationBar` (or the other bar classes) and override `drawRect:` in the subclass.